# How to get smaller cols to match their sibling's height?

Tags: css

I have a row and 2 columns are defining the height of the row which contains the 3 of them, but 1 of them is shorter in height. How can I make it stretch to the height of the row?

It looks disrupting.

Here's the html and css code:

```css
.customDiv {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt="" class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4 img-circle">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 customDiv">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3 customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A officiis accusamus est eaque voluptates! Aspernatur commodi natus iure ipsum, libero laudantium sequi praesentium beatae quia alias laboriosam dolor quos accusamus!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam iste, excepturi. Asperiores ad quaerat, autem, in hic laudantium ea, consequatur dolorum totam rem maiores architecto. Ipsa assumenda quis nisi consequuntur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione magni totam natus rem molestiae doloribus, at ipsa voluptatibus quam adipisci consectetur non voluptatum ullam id possimus maiores voluptates, esse assumenda.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates soluta nesciunt dolorem perferendis officiis pariatur magni eum illo fugit laudantium officia, sapiente blanditiis adipisci. Similique corporis nisi officiis soluta quod!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that an Element's height is defined by it's content, unless you define your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little bit of flexbox and you're all set:
https://jsfiddle.net/6jjk3s9q/

Added `display-flex flex-wrap-wrap` (both classes - utilities) to the row.

```
.display-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-wrap-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ur column parent css

```
  display: flex;
```

this will make its children take full height of container by default.

```css
.customDiv {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt="" class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4 img-circle">
    </div>

    <div class="row flex">
      <div class="col-sm-3 customDiv">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3 customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A officiis accusamus est eaque voluptates! Aspernatur commodi natus iure ipsum, libero laudantium sequi praesentium beatae quia alias laboriosam dolor quos accusamus!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam iste, excepturi. Asperiores ad quaerat, autem, in hic laudantium ea, consequatur dolorum totam rem maiores architecto. Ipsa assumenda quis nisi consequuntur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione magni totam natus rem molestiae doloribus, at ipsa voluptatibus quam adipisci consectetur non voluptatum ullam id possimus maiores voluptates, esse assumenda.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates soluta nesciunt dolorem perferendis officiis pariatur magni eum illo fugit laudantium officia, sapiente blanditiis adipisci. Similique corporis nisi officiis soluta quod!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Alternative Solution to Flex**

> `display:table` to **parent** and `display:table-cell` to **children**

```css
.customDiv {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3  col-xs-offset-4 img-circle">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="customDiv">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A officiis accusamus est eaque voluptates! Aspernatur commodi natus iure ipsum, libero laudantium sequi praesentium beatae quia alias laboriosam dolor quos accusamus!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam iste, excepturi. Asperiores ad quaerat, autem, in hic laudantium ea, consequatur dolorum totam rem maiores architecto. Ipsa assumenda quis nisi consequuntur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione magni totam natus rem molestiae doloribus, at ipsa voluptatibus quam adipisci consectetur non voluptatum ullam id possimus maiores voluptates, esse assumenda.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates soluta nesciunt dolorem perferendis officiis pariatur magni eum illo fugit laudantium officia, sapiente blanditiis adipisci. Similique corporis nisi officiis soluta quod!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**Flex Solution**

`display:flex` to **parent**

It's better to add another class instead of `row` and give it property of `display:flex` to avoid further complications while using class `row` in your project.

```css
.customDiv {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.flex-me {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3  col-xs-offset-4 img-circle">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row flex-me">
      <div class="col-xs-4 customDiv">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmkCF_wgI5tCnplsBhDh23wy7psxUHLwiF2sVfxyPAswOcLfI8hQ" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4 customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A officiis accusamus est eaque voluptates! Aspernatur commodi natus iure ipsum, libero laudantium sequi praesentium beatae quia alias laboriosam dolor quos accusamus!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam iste, excepturi. Asperiores ad quaerat, autem, in hic laudantium ea, consequatur dolorum totam rem maiores architecto. Ipsa assumenda quis nisi consequuntur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 customDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione magni totam natus rem molestiae doloribus, at ipsa voluptatibus quam adipisci consectetur non voluptatum ullam id possimus maiores voluptates, esse assumenda.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates soluta nesciunt dolorem perferendis officiis pariatur magni eum illo fugit laudantium officia, sapiente blanditiis adipisci. Similique corporis nisi officiis soluta quod!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The question has been answered half an hour ago in a better version. With just `display: flex` on it, the columns can't wrap anymore.

Comment: Well that doesn't mean that you are supposed to downvote all answers apart from your answer. That's so childish.

Comment: I didn't mean to downvote Gautam's answer, unfortunately it can't be reverted for now. Didn't see he included flex-wrap. But I downvoted your answer on purpose and commented why, `With just display: flex on it, the columns can't wrap anymore`.

Comment: No problem brother.. You can revert Gautam's answer by clicking on the downvote again.

Comment: I tried, it's just possible after an edit of the answer. I should really double-check the answer next time.